# Understanding the Binomial likelihood notation

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, likelihood, prior, posterior

Let $X \sim Bin(n,\pi)$.
I don't understand why the binomial likelihood is then given by $f(x|\theta)=\binom{n}{x} \theta^x (1-\theta)^{n-x}$. Shouldn't it be $B(x|\pi,n)=P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k} \pi^k (1-\pi)^{n-k} \Rightarrow L(\pi)=P(x|\theta)=\Pi^{N}_{i=1} \binom{n}{x_i} \theta^{x_i} (1-\theta)^{n-x_i} = \Pi^{N}_{i=1}\binom{n}{x_i} \theta^{\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i} (1- \theta)^{Nn-\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i}$

Leading to $\pi \sim Beta(\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i+\alpha, Nn-\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i+\beta)$

Maybe my notation is wrong. It maybe because I am little bit confused by the $n$ and $N$ which I can't really distinguish.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking at $N$ independent samples from $Bin(n,\theta)$?  If so, your expressions involving sums and products are reasonable.  Incidentally, the ${n \choose x_i}$ coefficients in the binomial probabilities do not involve $\theta$ and so can be dropped from the likelihood and proportionality statements. You are left with $\propto \theta^{\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i} (1- \theta)^{Nn-\sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i}$ which is the same as  $\propto \theta^{y} (1- \theta)^{m-y}$ where $y = \sum^{N}_{i=1} x_i$ and $m=Nn$, so the two approaches are equivalent, one with individual observations and the other sums.

Comment: This is not really specified within the exercise. But thanks for clarifying the $N$ and $n$ this makes sense. So for $N=1$ the likelihood is equal to the PMF for the Binomial distribution?

Comment: Yes - and even if $N >1$ you still have a likelihood proportional to the PMF of a binomial distribution.